# Is inheritance appropriate here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have one class that creates an object (a box) and contains strategies to rearrange it's contents. I think this should be two classes, however, since I usually use FP, I'm unsure of how to make the `box class` work with the `solver class` that contains strategies to rearrange the contents of the box.

Can `box` be a subclass of `solver`? It doesn't seem right. If not, how can I make the two work together?

```
class Box(object):        
    def __init__(self, contents, size):
         self.contents = contents
         self.size = size

    def fillBox (self, contents):
        pass


class Solver(object):        
    def __init__(self, boxObject, strategy):
        self.box = boxObject
        self.strategy = strategy

        if self.strategy == strategy1:
            self.strategy1()

    def strategy1 (self):
        // execute some algorithm manipulating the contents of the box
```

Comment: Can you replace all `solver`s, everywhere, with `box`es?
If yes, inheritance may be considered valid. If not, go the composition way.
"if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of the program (correctness, task performed, etc." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I think you're confusing inheritance and composition.

Comment: @Piohen most definitely not. A box is a box. A strategy is a method used to reconfigure its contents. That's the definition I had in the back of my head, but couldn't quite quote correctly.

Comment: It's not clear from your abbreviated example how your boxes and strategies are supposed to interact. Probably the only error in your code is `self.box.stragtegy1()` rather than `self.strategy1()` (since the strategy is a method of the solver, not a method of the box). I don't see anywhere that inheritance would make much sense here, though perhaps you could have hierarchies of solver and box subclasses if that seemed useful.

Comment: @Ryan: then don't use inheritance. Inheritance isn't meant for code reuse. It's meant for "creating nice types".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual question to ask yourself is: "Is ____ a ____?" where the first blank is the proposed subclass, the second the proposed superclass, in this case "Is `Box` a `Solver`?" If the answer is no (which seems to be the case here), inheritance is inappropriate. What you've done to make `Solver` accept a `Box` as an argument that becomes an instance attribute is the correct way to go about it.